# how can I force automatic filling to be enabled on webpages?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, auto-form-fill

I'm using the Chrome Browser.  I enjoy the "automatic filling" that it uses to fill in things like my address when I'm shopping online.

Sometimes I get a message that says:

*"This webpage has disabled automatic filling for this form"*

Is there a way that I can tell Chrome to ignore what the webpage wants and just give me what I want?

I'm not talking about passwords, I'm talking about Chrome's automatic filling in of things like my email address, zip code, etc.

For Example: https://www.kansas.gov/ump/register/account?

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973462/chrome-ugly-message-when-autofill-is-disabled) on StackOverflow. I'm not sure if it'll help much, but it'll clear some things out...

Comment: +1 for "ignore what the webpage wants and just give me what I want". Could not have said it better myself.

Answer (score 10):

Inherently there is no option to "auto-enable" completion even if a web page has disabled it. The web page disables it using the property `autocomplete=off` in an element. There is a chrome extension: [Auto-Complete = On](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh)

You can use that to turn on auto-complete for the elements that are disabled.

Comment: I figured that I'd probably need an extension to accomplish what I wanted.  I'll have to do some testing to see if this extension works.

Comment: This isn't what I want.  I edited my question to make it more obvious

Comment: The **Autocomplete = on** extension works sometimes but not always, so you may still need to use **Inspect Element** to edit the form property, as @curiousguy explains. Just beware, one reason people use this tag is because their crappy Javascript validation code can't correctly handle autofill.

Comment: I think that extension was removed?

Comment: A new one here; [Force Autocomplete](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/piechbhjioolbecaioglhamjjjkmbchj/publish-accepted?hl=en-US)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to install an extension:

You can right click on the form, select **Inspect Element** and edit the `auto-complete` attribute of the `<form>` element directly: change `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete=""`.

Comment: have to do this several times in order to bypass all of the fields.  It would be easier to just type in my name/address/city/state/zip

Comment: It would be easier but less pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Also your form must submit via `POST`. If you're submitting via ajax, do `<form autocomplete="on" method="post">`, omitting the `action` attribute.