# How can I autofill the "ID" field on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, automation, autocomplete, auto-form-fill

I fill out a form occasionally and want to be faster because signups fill rapidly. How do I get autofill for the ID field circled below? Chrome already does autocomplete for everything else (name, address, email, emergency contact) quickly - I just click on name, press the popup, and everything besides ID is filled. I've checked the settings and there's no autocomplete for ID, nor does my browser remember previous inputs for it.

I'm ok with using an extension if it's reasonable. The signup page is exactly the same every time, so I suppose the holy grail would be an extension which remembers the page layout and has everything filled the moment I land on it with no need to even click on a box and then click once more. Right now I'm already fast enough every time, but I want to rest on my laurels in case competition ramps up.

[image]

Comment: You will probably need a plugin to do this. The Chrome browser itself does not appear to support anything more than the standard form fields for autofill.

Comment: Note that google Autofill is not "looking" at the page the way you are; its reading its markup instead. Many webforms have hidden inputs for database IDs that are required by the application server-side, but are not designed to be filled by the user, so its likely that google would choose to exclude any field ending in "Id".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on why Chrome will not auto-fill that field. Website developers often explicitly disable it for various reasons, but you can sometimes override that by editing the field yourself or using an extension:

- **Extension:** just search for "Autocomplete" in the chrome web store. For example: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/autocomplete-on/kkffidhhikbopjomeeaihconieppiaan
- **Manual:** for most fillable web forms, you can follow [these steps](https://superuser.com/a/645283/673426). You will need to re-do if you refresh the page though:

> right click on the form, select **Inspect Element** and edit the auto-complete attribute of the `<form>` element directly: change `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete=""`.

Comment: Does that mean manual is useless? If you do that once and enter, the next time you'll get to the form you'll have to do it again hence you're just filling normally every time.

Comment: @Displayname yes, it's probably not useful for what you're doing. It can be helpful if you are filling a form multiple times on the same page for data entry, or if you were scripting/building an extension yourself